# cancelling an asynchronous call chain in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am looking into the problems of cancelling an async await chain in javascript and I came across [this tweet](https://twitter.com/getify/status/1171836419062542336) where the author states that in order to cancel a chain like this:

```js
  call1();
  call2();
  call3();
```

You would need to wrap them like this:

```js
 try {
    await Promise.race([
      call1(),
      isCanceled()
    ]);
  }
  catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof CancelationError) return;
  }

 try {
    await Promise.race([
      call2(),
      isCanceled()
    ]);
  }
  catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof CancelationError) return;
  }

 try {
    await Promise.race([
      call3(),
      isCanceled()
    ]);
  }
  catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof CancelationError) return;
  }
```

Which kind of makes since once you go into an `await` you never come out of it unless the promise either resolves or rejects.

I am told that you can cancel an entire chain using generators without wrapping every call.

Can anyone explain how you can wrap an entire chain without wrapping each async call?

Comment: Do you mean `await call1(); await call2(); await call3()`?

Comment: in your case, if call1 cancelled, no invoke of call2?

Comment: @NilankaManoj correct and no call3 either

Comment: @dagda1 I edited my answer and set three test cases

Comment: I found a good example [here](https://blog.bloomca.me/2017/12/04/how-to-cancel-your-promise.html#switch-to-generators),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could wrap this in a generator which yields the promises, and then for each promise does the race with the cancellation:

```
async function run(cancel, fn) {
  const gen = fn();
  let result = gen.next();
  let next;
  while (!result.done) {
    try {
      next = await Promise.race([cancel, result.value]);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof CancelationError)
        result = gen.return();
      else
        result = gen.throw(err);
      continue;
    }
    result = gen.next(next);
  }
}

run(isCanceled(), function*() {
  yield call1();
  yield call2();
  yield call3();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution, but you can poll a cancellation variable inside the promise :

```js
 const delay = (t) => new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve,t))//testing purpose

const call1 = () => new Promise(resolve=>
    {setTimeout(()=>{console.log("call1 finished");resolve("call1")},1000)})
const call2 = () => new Promise(resolve=>
    {setTimeout(()=>{console.log("call2 finished");resolve("call2")},1000)})
const call3 = () => new Promise(resolve=>
    {setTimeout(()=>{console.log("call3 finished");resolve("call3")},1000)})

let cancelled = false;

const isCancelled = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        const a = setInterval(()=>
             {
                 if(cancelled){reject("cancelled");clearInterval(a)}
             },50)
    })
}

async function process(){
    try{ 
         await Promise.race([call1(),isCancelled()])
         await Promise.race([call2(),isCancelled()])
         await Promise.race([call3(),isCancelled()])
       }
       catch(e){console.log(e)}
}
   
async function run(){
   console.log("test case 1 :")
   process();
   setTimeout(()=>cancelled=true,500)//test case 1 - only run call1()

   await delay(3000);cancelled = false
   
   console.log("test case 2 :")
   process();
   setTimeout(()=>cancelled=true,1500)//test case 2 - run call1() and call2()

   await delay(3000);cancelled = false

   console.log("test case 3 :")
   process();
   setTimeout(()=>cancelled=true,3000)//test case 3 - run call calls
}
run()
```

In the above three test cases :

- call1() completes all three
- call2() completes last two
- call3() completes only last one

Comment: Did you mean `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`?

Comment: This still requires wrapping every call which is what I was getting at in the question

Comment: setInterval should be there, is cancelled looking for the cancellation continuously.

Comment: @dagda1 what you mean by require wrapping? In my solution call1,2,3 calls directly.

Comment: I've updated the question, apologies if this was not obvious

Comment: look at Bergi's answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a generator, an async wrapper function can do the trick:

```js
function cancellableAsyncChain(...functions) {
  let cancelled = false;
  async function callFunctions() {
    for (let f of functions) {
      if (cancelled) {
        break; // for if you want the promise to resolve
        throw new CancellationError(); // for if you want the promise to reject
      }
      await f();
    }
  }
  const cancel () => {
    cancelled = true;
  }
  const promise = callFunctions();
  promise.cancel = cancel;
  return promise;
}

// Usage
async function f1() {}
async function f2() {}
async function f3() {}

let cancellablePromise = cancellableAsyncChain(f1, f2, f3);
setTimeout(() => cancellablePromise.cancel(), 1000);
cancellablePromise.then(
  () => console.log("Success"), 
  () => console.log("Error or cancelled")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need one generator to create pause-play generator function and a runner.

**generator:**

```
const generator = function* (cancelable, ...promies) {
  for (let i = 0; i < promies.length; i++) {
    yield Promise.race([promies[i](), cancelable]);
  }
};
```

**runner:**

```
async function runner(caller) {
  let finished = false;

  do {
    let { done, value } = caller.next();
    try {
      const data = await value;
      console.log(data);
      finished = done;
    } catch (error) {
      finished = true;
      console.log(error);
    }
  } while (!finished);
}
```

```js
const generator = function* (cancelable, ...promies) {
  for (let i = 0; i < promies.length; i++) {
    yield Promise.race([promies[i](), cancelable]);
  }
};

async function runner(caller) {
  let finished = false;

  do {
    let { done, value } = caller.next();
    try {
      const data = await value;
      console.log(data);
      finished = done;
    } catch (error) {
      finished = true;
      console.log(error);
    }
  } while (!finished);
}
runner(generator(cancelable(), call, call, call, call, call));

function cancelable() {
  return new Promise((r, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      rej("CANCELED");
    }, 2000);
  });
}

let count = 0;
function call() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(count++);
    }, 500);
  });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need to cancel an async / await chain ? Maybe the conception could be better ?
What do you think about this idea ?

```js
/** Throw new Error() in one of the following
 * call() will stop the execution and go the
 * catch block
 */
try {
    await call1();
    await call2();
    await call3();
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
```

Comment: many reasons.  one might be uploading a file in chunks and you want to cancel the whole upload

Comment: there is no cancellation in your code.  It would require a promise rejection to get thrown in each call in order to cancel the entire chain

Comment: I know you can use try catch with async await.  That is not what I am asking

Comment: how do I cancel at call2 and call3 does not get called?

Comment: You mean, you have one big file, and you need to split and send file part and if one part failed you want to cancel all call ?

Comment: the actual requirement was a cancel button but your example works also

Comment: The point is not that we can use try / catch but we have to use it with async / await. And yes, the point was to use single try catch for all calls. if you click the button, toggle one variable to false and use publish/subscribe pattern to emit an events that will be able to throw error inside async functions...

Comment: take a look at @Bergi's answer